# Nested function won't execute when calling it in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, nested

I'd like to create a navbar that will collapse when the screen is below a certain size, using jQuery, HTML and CSS, the website uses Wordpress, hence the

```
jQuery(function($) {...
```

Here's my code :

```
<div class="navbar-nav" id="nav-responsive">                    
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Créer mon plateau de fromages |</a>           
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/l-histoire-lepetit">L'histoire Lepetit |</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/le-camembert-lepetit">Le camembert Lepetit |</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/univers">L'univers Lepetit |</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/conseil">Les conseils Lepetit</a>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="bar-nav-container" onclick="showNav()">
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/menu-bar.png" id="bar-nav">
</a>

<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        function showNav() {
            // var navBlock = $('nav-responsive')
            $('#bar-nav-container').click(function () { 
                alert("click");                     
            });
        }

        showNav();
    });
</script>
```

I want the bar-nav-container to execute showNav when it is clicked on. The alert("click") is just a way to make sure my function is really called. What's wrong with my code ? When I click it says showNav is not defined.. I tried to call the function with :

```
onclick="$(showNav())"
```

And it still doesn't work. Any help please ? Thanks !

Comment: the reason your code is not working is that `showNav()` is not available in the "global namespace" (in JS parlance, you say "on the window object"). It is defined in a closure and only available there, not outside! This is, in fact, desired bahaviour if used correctly and can prevent you from doing Bad Things ;-)

Answer (score 1):

"bar-nav-container" is your class and function should be outside. 
your script should be something like this.

```
function showNav(){
                  //do whatever you want
}
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.bar-nav-container').click(function () { 
        alert("click"); showNav();                    
   });
});
```

Comment: Oh okay so basically I should write the function outside the jQuery(function($)), and call it inside the latter ?

Comment: Thanks, the function is executed ! I tried this now : function showNav(){$('.navbar-nav').css("display", "block"}. Now it tells me " $ is not a function ". Should I put " $ " as a parameter ?

Comment: if still error will come please add JQuery referenece.